# Android Studio has rare behavior

Tags: java, android-studio

I opened the Android Studio and, it is having a strange behavior, when I closed the IDE my app was functioning correctly, now when I opened again, it shows several errors, like the image.

If you know why this is happening, please help me to correct it.

[image]

It is showing code I never have developed.

[image]

Comment: Do a Refresh and a full Rebuild.

Comment: Hi Andreas, could you elaborate a few your response please? I can't see the Refresh option

Comment: **Web Search**: [`android studio refresh`](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+studio+refresh)

Comment: Thanks for your response, the problem is not the layout isn't refreshing, the problems are:
- Some files are showing rare characters (Gradle Scripts folder)
- Some java files are showing one aditional file with errors, these files always start with name vcard* (like image above)

Thanks for some help.

SS